# Error when outputting php and javascript from inside quotes or heredoc

Tags: php, javascript, html, for-loop, heredoc

I keep getting the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL" when attempting to use the following code :

```
<?php 
$names = array(1 => 'example1', 2 => 'example2',    3 => 'example3', 4 => 'example4');

$code = <<<HEREDOC<div><h3>$names[$i]</h3>
    <div class="rating"><div class="id$i" id="0
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, 'SELECT userid, rating FROM ranks WHERE userid = ? AND id =?');
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $userid, $i);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userid, $i, $rating);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                echo ($rating);
            }_$i"><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".id' . $i. '").jRating({isDisabled : false});});</script></div></div><div class="push"> 
        $query = "SELECT ROUND( AVG(rating),1 ) FROM ranks WHERE fight_id ='".$i."'");
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error querying database.");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<h3 class='average'>" . $row["ROUND( AVG(rating),1 )"] . "/5" . "</h3>";}
        </div><br/></div><div class="line"></div>;HEREDOC;


for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo $code
}?>
```

I'm sure I'm going at it wrong, I've tried using php opening and closing tags every time it switches to JS/HTML and also tried using single quotes and got errors. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The correct style of heredoc is:

```
$code = <<<HEREDOC

HEREDOC;
```

each notation should be at beginning of the line and ends with line break.

UPDATE: as mentioned by @Mike

> can't assign variables or do while loops within HEREDOC notation

Comment: Not to mention you can't assign variables or do while loops within HEREDOC notation.

Comment: Thanks @Mike I added your comment

Comment: So how should I be approaching this? using php tags to deliniate the html and JS, or using quotes and .'s? (Both of which I've failed to get working before.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: there is an error in the code.
The line

```
$query = "SELECT ROUND( AVG(rating),1 ) FROM ranks WHERE fight_id ='".$i."'");
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT ROUND( AVG(rating),1 ) FROM ranks WHERE fight_id ='".$i."')";
```

Second: an alternative solution is to concatenate your content

```
<?php 
$names = array(1 => 'example1', 2 => 'example2',    3 => 'example3', 4 => 'example4');

$code = '<div><h3>'.$names[$i].'</h3>
    <div class="rating"><div class="id'.$i.'" id="0'.(
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, 'SELECT userid, rating FROM ranks WHERE userid = ? AND id =?');
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $userid, $i);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userid, $i, $rating);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                echo ($rating);
            }).'_'.$i.'"><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".id' . $i. '").jRating({isDisabled : false});});</script></div></div><div class="push">'.( 
        $query = "SELECT ROUND( AVG(rating),1 ) FROM ranks WHERE fight_id ='".$i."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error querying database.");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<h3 class='average'>" . $row["ROUND( AVG(rating),1 )"] . "/5" . "</h3>";}).'
        </div><br/></div><div class="line"></div>';


for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo $code
}?>
```

Suggestion: transform things like the queries in functions (and the call these functions when you need it) so your code is cleaner and more comprehensible.